# Is it safe to make a splash screen this way?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I have made this splash screen for my app but im not sure whether is the best option. As it is sleeping the thread when the app is launching. Here is the code, I use navigation components so the weren´t tutorials available.
SplashFragment.kt

```
class SplashFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var rootview:View

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    splash()
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_splash, container, false)

    return rootview
}

fun splash(){
    Thread(Runnable {
        Thread.sleep(500)
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_splahFragment_to_loginFragment)
    }).start()
}
```

}

Comment: Use delay method of Handler class instead of this Thread.sleep as sleep freezes the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is good, but it is not safe, it will anyways spawn a new `Thread` when you call `start` and that `thread` will `sleep` all good so far but you need to call `navController` from UI thread, also if user quits the app before `500` milliseconds it will crash.

Here is a solution `Kotlin coroutines` way

```
val mDelayJob: CompletableJob = Job() 
//use mDelayJob to cancel coroutine in onStop, so if even user exits before delay, nothing will happen
fun splash(){
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch(mDelayJob){
        delay(500)
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_splahFragment_to_loginFragment)
    }
}
```

Comment: You could just use `lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted` so the job will be cancelled for you.

Comment: Yep makes sense

Comment: Do you know why a white screen is appearing before the splash screen?

Answer (score 1):

Thread.sleep(time) freezes the UI. So use Handler to delay the launch.

Update your splash function:

```
fun splash(){
     Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(Runnable {
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_splahFragment_to_loginFragment)
    }, 500)
}
```

Comment: `Thread.sleep(500)` only freeze UI if its main thread . As per OPs code its not a Main thread .

Answer (score 0):

For now it looks safe, as You are sleeping the tread only for 500 millis. But it would not be safe in case If you increase the sleep time in future.

Let me explain how, Suppose You are sleeping a thread for 10000 mills (i.e. 10 secs) And before 10 seconds If you navigate to any other component(say fragments or activities) then when after 10 seconds, when Your thread tries to execute next line, this fragment would not be visible and would cause an issues.

So as a best practice, You would interrupt the thread on `onStop` method of your fragment and countiously check inside runnable, that is your thread inturrupted or not. And if it is not inturuppted then only execute next tasks

Comment: Pretty sure the current way will crash if the user presses back before 500ms are up.